# Thymeleaf page how check user logged in or not

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

I have spring thymeleaf page I want check if user logged in or not. If true check notification to update if not login so no need to check and use resources.
I try get in javascript like this :

```
[[${#authentication.getPrincipal().getName()}]];
```

but it work only when user login.  I try

```
  <li sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"> <span id="id" sec:authentication="name"></span></li>
```

get value by id and this also not working.
Is there some standard working method to check user login or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem with this code that return true or false related to authentication:

```
<span th:text="${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}"></span>
```

And this one could use in javascript:

```
= [[${#authorization.expression('isAuthenticated()')}]];
```